# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method

Tags: linq-to-entities

```
string[] userIds = userList.Split(','); // is an array of integers
IList<User> users = (from user in this.repository.Users
                     where userIds.Contains(user.Id.ToString())
                     select user).ToList();
```

the above query gives

`System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression`

What can I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Avoid the call to `ToString`. You want something like this:

```
userIds.Contains(user.Id)
```

To make this work the list `userIds` must be a collection of the type which `user.Id` has. If you want integers then use `int.Parse` to convert the strings to integers:

```
int[] userIds = userList.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 14):

use can use something like this,

```
where userIds.Contains(SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)user.Id))
```

instead of `where userIds.Contains(user.Id.ToString())`

this should work