# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012

`Error Description:` LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

The error comes up while executing following code:

```
public ActionResult NewBooking()
    {
        var db = new VirtualTicketsDBEntities2();

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Attractions
          .Select(c => new SelectListItem
          {
              Value = c.A_ID.ToString(),
              Text = c.Name
          });
        ViewBag.CategoryID = items;
        return View();
    }
```

Any suggestion to get rid of this error?

Thanks.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899683/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring-method?rq=1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121863/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring-method)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use an `AsEnumerable()` to change the binding context from Linq-to-Entities to Linq-to-Objects:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Attractions
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(c => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = c.A_ID.ToString(),
        Text = c.Name
    });
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I will mark your answer correct in 9 minutes.

Comment: Just use `AsEnumerable()` ... `ToList()` is a costly step depending on how much items there are.

Comment: This looks really inefficient. If table Attractions is large, we fill a big list of tuples then execute our query.

Comment: @SimonBelanger There's no filter in the example, so it's not puling any more records than the original code.

Comment: @DStanley I agree, but ToList() effectively builds up the list. You will create an intermediate `List<Attraction>` to then project to the `SelectListItem`. `AsEnumerable()` will only iterate the `Attraction`s, not creating a list.

Comment: @SimonBelanger So what's your alternative?  You _could_ project to an anonymous type, then to `SelectListItem`, but that seems unnecessary unless `Attraction` is a very heavy class.

Comment: @DStanley Why project to an anonymous type at all? `db.Attractions.AsEnumerable` will be strongly typed to `Attraction` and then you project to your `SelectListItem`, there's no need for an anonymous object as intermediate. The only different is `ToList` is building the list. The query will still be serialized as `Attraction` then to `SelectList` without the cost of creating a `List<Attraction>`.

Comment: @SimonBelanger I'm with you now - I was thinking you were objecting to hydrating `Attraction` ojects - now I see that the additional overhead of copying to a new list is the issue.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do the conversion on the database, you need to use an [`SqlFunction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions_methods.aspx):

```
public ActionResult NewBooking()
{
    var db = new VirtualTicketsDBEntities2();

    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Attractions
      .Select(c => new SelectListItem
      {
          Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.A_ID)
          Text = c.Name
      });
    ViewBag.CategoryID = items;
    return View();
}
```

The problem is the `SqlFunctions` are not standard and might not work on all database providers. If that's a problem, use `AsEnumerable` to leave the Entity Framework's queryable world:

```
public ActionResult NewBooking()
{
    var db = new VirtualTicketsDBEntities2();

    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Attractions.AsEnumerable()
      .Select(c => new SelectListItem
      {
          Value = c.A_ID.ToString()
          Text = c.Name
      });
    ViewBag.CategoryID = items;
    return View();
}
```